# Did Team Rocket’s Meowth ever get an opportunity to evolve into Persian?

Tags: pokemon

Team Rocket’s Meowth has been in the show since the second episode of the *Pokémon* anime and is still around over a thousand episodes and over 20 movies later. Did he ever get the chance to evolve into a Persian (that was perhaps turned down, like Ash’s Pikachu and Ash’s Bulbasaur)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Refusal

Within the show we never see Meowth *turn down* an evolution to Persian but we do know that he's deeply contemptuous of his evolved form, as seen in (amongst others) [POK: Mean with Envy](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/AG115) when Meowth literally becomes incandescent with rage at the mere sight of a Persian. Presumably he'd refuse to evolve if the opportunity arose.

> Meowth: [Angrily] - No Persian's making a Mankey out of me!!
>
> [image]

### XP

It's worth noting that Meowth rarely battles and doesn't seem know any of the advanced dark Pokemon moves that are common to his type. In [POK: Meowth Rules](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/EP096), he states that

> **Meowth:** *I put so much energy into learning how to talk that I just can't learn Pay Day*

Frankly it's possible that he's simply not got enough XP to evolve even if he wanted to. Not only has he not won a single legitimate battle in the show's entire run but he didn't even manage to *hit* Pikachu until [more than 850 episodes in](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/XY079). It's also possible that his lack of slots has somehow stunted his capacity to evolve.